# NodeJs - Seeing strange behaviour - possibly event loop stuck case

Tags: mysql, node.js, libuv

Recently we observed a behavior in our production. Below is the scenario.

We are using nodejs and mysql server

There is a api call which contains four steps

```
 1 Insert a record.
 2 Make a upstream call and get a id 
 3 Update the record with the id created in step 1
 4 Send a email.
```

Below is step wise strange behaviour which we saw.

```
- We got this api call on lets say day 1. 
 - Step 1 completed succcessfully as seen in our db and logs.
 - They were no further updates and none of the steps 2,3,4 executed .There was nothing in db and strangely nothing was in the logs related to step 2 ,3 ,4 .
 - Next day when we came , we saw that step 2, 3, 4 were executed. We could see everything in the logs as well as db and updated_at was of second day.
```

My question is about explanation on this. This seems like a node js bug where callback after step 1 was stuck and never came back on day 1. Possibly on day 2 the callback executed and everything went fine. This seems like a event loop bug in libuv or node event loop.

As anybody observed similar behaviour and how to fix it. We are observing similar behaviour for another records as well.

Comment: Without seeing any code it's hard to say what happened. Did happen only once or it happens all the time?

Comment: It has happened for 5 records(1 percent) only on that day. I don't think it's a code issue . What is even more surprising is was one of the record got stuck at step 1 and next day we saw db entries and logs for all steps 1-4. It's more like we see a problem and then if fixes itself.

Comment: Usually problems don't fix themselves. My two cents.